# UITableView not displaying prototype cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard

I am trying to make an app that connects to chromecast to play a video on TV, up till now I am still trying to display the video links using two view controllers, one contains a webview that makes the user gets the video page, the other is to display all video links inferred from the first view to make the user select which video to cast from the page. I am able to get the links but the problem is it doesn't want to be displayed in the table view cells. I have tried many methods but I noticed, for some reason the UITableViewDataSource methods are not being called at all. Here is the code:

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    //MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBarTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    //MARK: Properties
    static var videoURLs: [String] = []

    //MARK: Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        cancelButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cancelButton.isHidden = true
        webView.delegate = self

    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        var videoTag = ""
        var embedTag = ""
        let htmlCode = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.documentElement.outerHTML")
        let htmlTags = htmlCode!.components(separatedBy: "\n") as [String]
        for tag in htmlTags{
            var videoURL = ""
            if tag.contains("<video") {
                videoTag = tag.substring(from: tag.range(of: "<video")!.lowerBound)
                videoTag = videoTag.substring(to: (videoTag.range(of: ">")?.upperBound)!)
                if videoTag.contains("src"){
                    videoTag = tag.substring(from: tag.range(of: "src")!.upperBound)
                    for x in videoTag.characters{
                        if x == "\""{
                            continue
                        }else if x == "="{
                            continue
                        }else if x == ">"{
                            break
                        }else{
                            videoURL.append(x)
                        }
                    }
                }
                ViewController.videoURLs.append(videoURL)
            }
            if tag.contains("<embed") {
                embedTag = tag.substring(from: tag.range(of: "<embed")!.lowerBound)
                embedTag = embedTag.substring(to: (embedTag.range(of: ">")?.upperBound)!)
                if embedTag.contains("src"){
                    embedTag = tag.substring(from: tag.range(of: "src")!.upperBound)
                    for x in embedTag.characters{
                        if x == "\""{
                            continue
                        }else if x == "="{
                            continue
                        }else if x == ">"{
                            break
                        }else{
                            videoURL.append(x)
                        }
                    }
                }
                ViewController.videoURLs.append(videoURL)
            }
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "Done")))
    }

    //MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func cancelPressed() {
        cancelButton.isHidden = true
        searchBarTrailingConstraint.constant = 0.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func searchBarPressed() {
        searchBarTrailingConstraint.constant = (cancelButton.frame.width + 8.0) * -1
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        cancelButton.isHidden = false
    }

    @IBAction func returnButtonPressed(_ sender: UITextField) {
        cancelPressed()
        if let url = URL(string: sender.text!){
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
                let request = URLRequest(url: url)
                webView.loadRequest(request)
            }else{
                let googleSearchURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&q=\(url)&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8")
                let request = URLRequest(url: googleSearchURL!)
                webView.loadRequest(request)
            }
        }else{
            var searchString: [String] = []
            var searchWord = ""
            for x in (sender.text?.characters)!{
                if x == " "{
                    searchString.append(searchWord)
                    searchWord = ""
                }else{
                    searchWord.append(x)
                }
            }
            //For appending the last word not followed by a space
            if !(searchString.last == searchWord){
                searchString.append(searchWord)
            }
            var googleSearchURL = "https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q="
            for element in searchString{
                googleSearchURL.append(element)
                if !(searchString.last == element){
                    googleSearchURL.append("+")
                }

            }
            let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:googleSearchURL)!)
            webView.loadRequest(request)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if webView.canGoBack{
            webView.goBack()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func forwardButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if webView.canGoForward {
            webView.goForward()
        }
    }

}
```

MediaTableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class MediaTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    var videoURLs: [String] = []
    var videoScreenshots: UIImage!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MediaTableViewController.replyToNotification), name: nil, object: nil)

        self.tableView.dataSource = self

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videoURLs.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("NOW!\n\n\n", indexPath.count)

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MediaTableViewCell

        cell.videoImage.image = videoScreenshot(url: videoURLs[indexPath.count])
        cell.videoURL.text = videoURLs[indexPath.count]

        return cell
    }

    @objc func replyToNotification(){
        videoURLs = ViewController.videoURLs
        ViewController.videoURLs = []
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func videoScreenshot(url: String) -> UIImage? {

        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: url)!)
        let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

        do {
            let imageRef = try generator.copyCGImage(at: CMTime(value: asset.duration.value/2, timescale: asset.duration.timescale), actualTime: nil)
            return UIImage(cgImage: imageRef)
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("Image generation failed with error \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

MediaTableViewCell.swift:

```
import UIKit

class MediaTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var videoImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoURL: UITextView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

Here is the Main.storyboard:

[image: main.storyboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not call `reloadData()` thus the tableView is idle.

To fix this the following to `MediaTableViewController`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Didn't fix it, Still nothing appears

Comment: That is another problem. The original problem was that "UITableViewDataSource methods are not being called at all". That should be fixed using this solution. Please confirm. If the `dataSouce` methods are called and you get no entries in your `tableView`, `MediaTableViewController videoURLs.count` is most probably zero. In this case show where and how you set/add `MediaTableViewController videoURLs`.

Comment: I dont think the methods are being called, the NOW! is not being printed in the tableview method

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `numberOfRowsInSection`. It is called. `NOW!` is not printed because `MediaTableViewController videoURLs.count` is zero (as written) and thus `cellForRowAt indexPath` is never called.

Comment: yeah i set the number of rows, it got called now, but still the video url and photos don't show up, what is the problem now?

Comment: Update your question. Log  `videoURLs` in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: i tried printing the videoURLs array in viewDidAppear(_:) of class MediatableViewController, but it doesn't display anything, is there a problem with my notification code?

Comment: Yes. You have to send a `userInfo` dictionary with your notification, containing the `videoURLs`. I recommend against using notifications here thought. You should use Notifications only for to-many broadcasting.

Comment: I deleted the notification and changed the code, it now works great. Thanks so much @shallowThought, the first problem was the number of rows was 0 as you said and i don't know what was the cause of the second but it is solved now

Answer (score 0):

As I see you didn't implement tableView delegate

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MediaTableViewController.replyToNotification), name: nil, object: nil)
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

}
```

then add this method to your controller

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

hope this will help

Comment: One section is the default.